# How to use files from different directories in python?

Tags: python

I want to loop thru files from several directories.
I have several directories in one directory: dir

```
  import os
  >>> os.listdir('/path/dir/')
  ['Datax', 'Datay',  'BDA', 'RADI']
```

Read file from first directory:

```
   filein= open('/path/Datax/fileobs.txt', 'r') 
   #do something with file…………
   fileout = open('/path/Datax_{}_{}.txt'.format(V4, V5), 'w')# include the name of the directory in the name of the
```

now go to the second dirctory `Datay` and do the same :

```
    filein= open('/path/Datay/fileobs.txt', 'r') # just change the path to the second directory
    #do something with file…………
    fileout = open('/path/Datay_{}_{}.txt'.format(V4, V5), 'w')# include the name of the directory in the name of the
```

and so …….

the changes are here:

```
         filein= open('/path/change/fileobs.txt', 'r')
         # do something....
         fileout = open('/path/change_{}_{}.txt'.format(V4, V5), 'w')
```

Comment: The code you have written looks like it works fine. If it doesn't, can you post a stack trace? If it does, what are you trying to do that this code doesn't do?

Comment: One quick comment on your codes.  Please always remember to open and close a file when you make changes.  The best way is to use:

Comment: Adds to the previous comment: with open('/path/change/fileobs.txt', 'r') as filein: # do something.

Comment: look in the docs for `os.walk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dir_list = os.listdir('/path/dir/')

for a_dir in dir_list:
    filein= open('/path/'+a_dir+'/fileobs.txt', 'r') 
    fileout = open('/path/{}_{}_{}.txt'.format(a_dir,V4, V5), 'w')
```

We just iterate over the directories given by `os.listdir('/path/dir/')` and the include the variable in the text. Both fashion for including a variable in a text are here, `'text'+a_var+'text'` or `text{}text`.format(a_var)

Indeed you should close your files after, `file.close()` or use the with statement:

```
with open('path', 'r') as a_file:
    # do your things with the file
# file is closed outside the statement
```